# Error = "This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless"

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- android:background="@color/giris_arka_plan" -->
```

when i cancel comment like, it gives one more error about that background.

Also i closed all tags

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/txt_profil"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/profilImageButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/txt_profilePhoto"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_photo" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="30dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/kullaniciAdiEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/txt_kullaniciAdi"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/adEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/txt_adi"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/soyadEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/txt_soyadi"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/telefonEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/txt_telefon"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/txt_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/kaydetButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_Kaydet"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Its giving me this warning

> This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used LinearLayout in a RelativeLayout(parent) and the parent layout is not needed since its purposeless. You can change your layout like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/txt_profil"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/profilImageButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/txt_profilePhoto"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_photo" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="30dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/kullaniciAdiEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/txt_kullaniciAdi"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/adEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/txt_adi"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/soyadEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/txt_soyadi"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/telefonEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/txt_telefon"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/txt_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/kaydetButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_Kaydet"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use LinearLayout and RelativeLayout in same time its not make sense. Delete one of them to make your xml to have on Layout.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error but a warning telling you that one of those probably isn't needed. If a `View` or `ViewGroup` isn't needed then it is a waste of time to make your app inflate it.

Since you have basically 2 top-level `ViewGroups` there doesn't seem to be a need for both. So you could probably delete the `RelativeLayout` and get it to work the same. But if you wish to keep them then it will still compile and run with the warnings.

Comment: when i doing run, it doest not work.it says pls fix that line

Answer (score 0):

The topmost relative layout has no use.